# Does Apache log the http requests for same resource from different clients at same point of time

Tags: apache

I have create custom access log file and logging all the requests into the file.

**Doubt Scenario1**

When Does apache log to the access file??
     when request hit the server or when the server responded with response?

**Doubt Scenario2**

Requesting same resource from different clients at the same time . How apache serves the requests to all the clients?? Does the server logs the same time for all the requests??

My Point is .... will the requests from different clients to apache log at same time, does apache logs all the records with the same time into custom access log file(without any millisecond differences at least)?

Answer (score 0):

1) Apache will write to the log when the response has finished being sent, it has to wait until this point as you can configure the response time to be written to the log file.

2) A log line will be written for each individual request, so multiple clients requesting the same resource at the same time will each create an entry in the log file. Depending on how granular your time string is configured in the custom log, these may all appear with an equal date/time.

Comment: Thanks Arco:)    How apache handles all the requests at same time(no diff even in micro seconds).. It responds to each req one by one?? or any other concept behind this? can you please tell me how apache internally handles all the requests

Comment: It uses either forked processes or multi-threading to concurrently respond to each request. Read up on MPM worker and Prefork configurations on the Apache site if you want to know more.

Comment: Thanks Arco:) for the valuable info